# Making this confirmation dialog work in java

Tags: java, swing, confirmation

So I'm trying to have a confirmation dialog box work in my program asking if the user would like to upgrade their membership using import javax.swing.JOptionPane

However, when i go to execute, the program always reverts to as if I clicked "Yes". Help please?

```
int option =
                     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                             "Would you like to become a member for $4.95?",
                             "Upgrade Membership",
                             JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
             if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you. Your membership fee will be"
                         + " added to your receipt.");
                         dFee = 4.95;
                         sMember = "Premium";
             }
             if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for your consideration.");
                 sMember = "Regular";
             }
             if (answer == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You may purchase a membership in the"
                         + " future.");
                 sMember = "Regular";
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is perhaps the most apparent problem with the snippet provided is that two different variables are being used for the answer.  `option` is the variable actually receiving the response from the user, whereas `answer` is defined elsewhere, is never assigned to, but is being used in the `if` statements.

In short, use `option` instead of `answer` in the `if` statements.

Comment: Sheesh, so many people downvoting, give me a break here.

Anyways, thanks, that worked.